# Read and store dataframe with each iteration

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I need a simple code to create a loop that goes to a several subfolders and reads the file there in each iteration. After reading I want to store the data using the name of a factor that I have. The factor has 19 levels and I want to read 19 files of 19 subfolders. For now, everytime the loop overwrites the data because the read data is always stored with the same name and is not looping through the names of the factor.

Code that I tried:

```
    # read data table for each region in the control period
for(l in 1:length(regions)){
  name <- regions@data$name[l]
  setwd(paste("filepath","/",name,sep=""))
  data <- read.table(paste(name,".mit",sep=""),skip=1,header=TRUE)
  data$Date <- paste(data$YYYY,"-",data$MM,"-",data$DD,sep="")
  data$Date <- as.POSIXct(data$Date,format="%Y-%m-%d")
}
```

Comment: please include the code you already tried...

Comment: try with `assign()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing your data, etc., what you want is to read all the contents of the different files into R? Then you need to provide your loop something to return to your workspace. Using [`assign()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assign.html) you can create a dataframe for each individual region like so:

```
 for(l in 1:length(regions)){
      name <- regions@data$name[l]
      setwd(paste("filepath","/",name,sep=""))
      data <- read.table(paste(name,".mit",sep=""),skip=1,header=TRUE)
      data$Date <- paste(data$YYYY,"-",data$MM,"-",data$DD,sep="")
      data$Date <- as.POSIXct(data$Date,format="%Y-%m-%d")
      df_name <- paste0("dataframe_",name)
      assign(df_name  ,data, envir=.GlobalEnv)

    }
```

Comment: This code worked and I have now stored the data in my global environment. Just the data of each region is now named after the region short name. To achieve this, you have to replace df_name <- paste0("dataframe_",l) with df_name <- paste0(name).